# Manually install a printer without running any cups command

Tags: cups, printer, live-build

I need to manually install a printer without running any cups command, by copying files from a Debian system where the printer is already installed.

I have to proceed by this way in order to make a Debian live DVD where the printer will be installed. So, if I use the Canon installer, it will connect to the cups server of the host, and will install the printer on the host, instead of installing it in the chroot.

The printer is a Canon G3560, connected on usb. The device URI is `cnijbe2://Canon/?port=usb&serial=60A386`.

I have copied the driver's Debian package `cnijfilter2_6.10-1_amd64.deb` in `config/packages.chroot/` of the live DVD building directory.

And I have copied the files `/etc/cups/ppd/G3060USB.ppd` and `/etc/cups/printers.conf` to the live DVD building directory: `config/includes.chroot_after_packages/etc/cups/`.

When I run the live system, it shows the printer, but the system is unable to print any document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem, looking at the file `/var/log/cups/error_log`, it said that it failed to read the ppd file.

The file `G3060USD.ppd` in the directory `config/includes.chroot_after_packages/etc/cups/ppd/` must be readable by every user that need to use the printer.

So, I made this file readable to "others", with the command `chmod o+r ./G3060USD.ppd`.

Another way to solve the problem may be to set the owner group of the ppd file to "lp", if the users that will use the printer are members of the group "lp". But I don't know if it is possible to solve the problem by this way in the case of building a Debian live DVD.